# Not Your Regular Chess Challenge

Tags: logical-deduction, chess

Imagine that you have a normal 8x8 chessboard and you have an unlimited amount of all kinds of chess pieces. Find the greatest and lowest number of pieces you can have in that chessboard without those pieces being able to attack each other if :

1. You have to pick exactly 3 different kinds of chess pieces
2. You have to pick exactly 4 different kinds of chess pieces
3. You have to pick exactly 5 different kinds of chess pieces

To clarify :

> What kind of chess pieces you pick is entirely up to you.

Comment: Just as a comment -- not to take anything away from @sedrick's answer -- but it might be best if you either didn't accept an answer yet or write in the title that part of it is still unsolved. I know that I personally tend not to look at "solved" puzzles with an accepted answer (unless they look interesting, like this one), so you might get more viewer traffic if this puzzle doesn't appear to be solved. Just my two cents, though! :)

Comment: Hmm, I guess you're right. Thx for the suggestion :) @El-Guest

Comment: A couple of questions: 1: are all pieces the same colour, or can I use pawns going both ways? 2: pieces of the same colour can attack each other, right? 3: Is there some sort of extra information that makes the "lowest number" question more sensible?

Comment: Answer : 1 and 2. All pieces will try to eat each other so place them so that they cannot reach each other. Colour does not matter. 3. Oh yeah. I forgot, place them so that they cannot attack each other. Gonna edit that :) @Bass

Comment: Continuing 1: Still unclear. Is this correct: different coloured pawns are ok, but they count as the same kind? This is important, because a white pawn cannot be on rank 8, but a black pawn can. Also, different coloured pawns attack in opposite directions. 3: that still doesn't make any sense. Putting exactly 3 different chess pieces on the board so that they don't attack each other isn't exactly a challenge.

Comment: Let's just say for the sake of this question that all the chess pieces are all black and black pawns placed on rank 1 will still be a black pawn @Bass. I'll also edit the question

Comment: "unable to move anywhere without getting eaten" is totally different question than the original question that you wrote... dont change questions totally after a day -.-

Comment: I wrote it in a hurry before so I'm very sorry! U can still downvote my question BTW if that will make u forgive me :) @Oray

Comment: This question is getting very messy. In order for it not to become a train wreck, you should probably restore the original question, and make a whole new question from the edited bits.

Comment: ok thx for the suggestion. Will do just that :)@Bass

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My initial thoughts for maximum:

3 types

> 31 
>  Pawns on rows 1,3,5,8. Replace B8 with knight and H8 with king. Remove G8 pawn.

4 types

> 29 
>  Same as above then replace D8 with bishop and remove the 2 pawns it attacks (A5 and G5)

5 types

> 27 
>  Same as above then put rook on A7 and remove pawns on A1, A3, A8.

Comment: Gotta take back that check mark @sedrick

Comment: As a token of apology, please have my upvote though! +1

Comment: Yup no problem. I get where you're coming from too

Comment: +1 from me too :)) @sedrick

Answer (score 5):

Here are **the lowest** that I have found by using Queen minimum;

with 3 lowest (6 pieces):

> [image]

with 4 lowest (7 pieces):

> [image]

with 5 lowest (8 pieces):

> [image]

Here is the highest amount of pieces that you can put:

with 3 lowest (32 pieces)

> [image]

with 4 lowest (31 pieces)

> [image]

with 5 highest (27 pieces)

> [image]

Comment: If I understand the rules correctly, if you can move one of the pieces to a position where it isn't attacked, then you have not solved the puzzle. In the low, 3 piece, the queen on G8 could move to E8 without being attacked. If OP did not mean this, the rules should likely be adjusted to remove "unable to move anywhere without being eaten".

Comment: @JoelRondeau puzzle has been changed after a day so I lost interest solving it :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you ask for "greatest and lowest", here's the lowest:

> 1. knight a1, pawn b2, rook c3
>  2. the above plus king h8
>  3. the above plus bishop h2

Comment: I interpreted the lowest as that I cannot add another piece of the same type on board anywhere

Comment: yes that is what I meant

Comment: Makes sense. I knew there had to be something I was missing.